# how to design Android Pattern Lock Screen in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, lockscreen

I Want to create an android Pattern lock screen in my iphone app...
but i don't know how to do that... i searched a lot but nothing got..
Can anybody have an idea how to do that in iphone???
Plz help me to solve my problem.. .thanx

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
 {

  tapCount=0;
  attempt=0; 
  password=@"";

tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(cancel:)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:YES];



[super viewDidLoad];
self.passwordSet=NO;
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay the android pattern lock for IOS can be done using the sample code provided [here](https://github.com/GrioSF/Android-Pattern-Lock-on-iOS)

Comment: Thanx @Sumanth   i want this with ARC OFF... but it doesn't work//

Comment: See you should do some task. make the code with by adding release or if you are not that much then `Add the flag -fobjc-arc to the files that you'd like to use ARC. It's just the opposite of the other.`

Answer (score 2):

This is what you are looking for: http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/alunlockpatternview